# Excel macro stops running by itself when I switch to another Excel file

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on a macro-enabled Excel file that I want to work like a timesheet. There's a button that the user will press and the current time will be stamped in the start column; if the user presses it again, the current time will be stamped in the finish column. If the user started a cycle and the PC goes 5 minutes without user interaction, the cycle will be ended and the time will automatically be stamped in the finish cell. When the cycle is started, a timer of 5 minutes runs. If there is no PC activity before the 5 minute timer ends, the time will be stamped and the cycle will end.
The code detects PC inactivity, not just within Excel.

When I open or work on another workbook, the macro/timer stops. I need the macro to continue running even if I'm working on another Excel file.

I've tried the DoEvents workaround, but it didn't work. I read that there's a bug when Workbook.Open is used but I didn't use Workbook.Open in any of my modules. When I open another Excel file, it's just by locating the file on my desktop and double-clicking it.

I've been trying to declare a Global variable to get and store the name of the worksheet (because other people will be making copies of it and using it too, the name of the worksheet will most likely be changed) because I have a feeling it has something to do with my code that identifies the active cell.

Sheet1

```vb
Dim mRg As Range
Dim mStr As String

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim WorkRng As Range
Dim Rng As Range
Dim xOffsetColumn As Integer
Set WorkRng = Intersect(Application.ActiveSheet.Range("A:A"), Target)
xOffsetColumn = 5

If Not WorkRng Is Nothing Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    For Each Rng In WorkRng
        If Not VBA.IsEmpty(Rng.Value) Then
            Rng.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn).Value = Date
        Else
            Rng.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn).ClearContents
        End If
    Next
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End If

    'Locking the entire third column with a password
    Dim xRg As Range
    On Error Resume Next
    Set xRg = Intersect(Range("C:C"), Target)
    If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Target.Worksheet.Unprotect Password:="password"
    If xRg.Value <> mStr Then xRg.Locked = True
    Target.Worksheet.Protect Password:="password"

End Sub


Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

If Not Intersect(Range("C:C"), Target) Is Nothing Then
    Set mRg = Target.Item(1)
    mStr = mRg.Value
End If
End Sub
```

ThisWorkbook

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

    Dim lA As Long
    'Last non-blank cell of column A (Start)

    Dim lB As Long
    'Last non-blank cell of column B (Finish)

        lA = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        lB = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

    If lA <> lB Then
    'If there's an unfinished cycle, execute the following:
        Call Range_End_Method
        Call TimeStartStop
        ThisWorkbook.Save
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    End If

    If lA = lB Then
    'If there's no unfinished cycle, save the sheet and immediately close the sheet
        ThisWorkbook.Save
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    End If

End Sub
```

Module 1

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Range_End_Method()
'Finds the last non-blank cell in a single row or column


Dim FirstBlankCell As Range
Set FirstBlankCell = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
FirstBlankCell.Activate


End Sub
```

Module2

```vb
Private Type LASTINPUTINFO
   cbSize As Long
   dwTime As Long
End Type

Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetLastInputInfo Lib "user32" (lii As LASTINPUTINFO) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetTickCount Lib "kernel32" () As Long

'Getting number of seconds idle/user inactivity on PC, not just Excel
Private Function GetIdleSecs()
    Dim LastInput As LASTINPUTINFO
    With LastInput
        .cbSize = Len(LastInput)
        Call GetLastInputInfo(LastInput)
        GetIdleSecs = (GetTickCount() - .dwTime) / 1000
    End With
End Function

Public Sub checkIdle()

    Dim lA As Long
    'Last non-blank cell of column A (Start)

    Dim lB As Long
    'Last non-blank cell of column B (Finish)

    lA = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    lB = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

    'If block for if the sheet is blank
    If lA = 4 Then
        lA = 6
    End If
    If lB = 4 Then
        lB = 6
    End If

    DoEvents
    'Number of seconds idle
    Dim idleSecs As Long: idleSecs = GetIdleSecs()

    If lA <> lB Then
    'If there's a running cycle, execute the following
        'For Debugging purposes; this shows up in the immediate Window which you can open by pressing Ctrl + G
        Debug.Print "Idle for"; idleSecs

        'If number of seconds idle is less than 5 minutes, the timer will continue counting and updating every second
        If idleSecs < 300 Then
            Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"), "checkIdle", False
        End If

        'idleSecs is the number of seconds needed before the whole If Block is executed
        '300 seconds because 5 minutes x 60 seconds
        If idleSecs = 300 Then
            Call Module1.Range_End_Method
            Call Module3.TimeStartStop

            'Save the current workbook
            ThisWorkbook.Save

            'Message box: First parameter is the message body, third parameter is the alert title
            MsgBox "TMS has stopped due to 5 minutes of inactivity. Your workbook has automatically been updated and saved.", , "TMS Stopped"

            'Sub is automatically closed once 5 minutes is reached and the timer is stopped
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If

    If lA = lB Then
        'If there's no running cycle, execute the following:
        'For debugging purposes
        'Debug.Print "Doing nothing..."
    End If

End Sub

Public Sub doNothing()
    'For debugging purposes
    'Debug.Print "Doing nothing..."
End Sub
```

Module3

```vb
Sub TimeStartStop()

CR = ActiveCell.Row

CC = ActiveCell.Column

If CC <= 2 And CR >= 6 Then
    TS = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Name

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(TS).Cells(CR, CC) = Now
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(TS).Cells(CR, CC + 1).Select
    If CC = 2 And ThisWorkbook.Sheets(TS).Cells(CR, 1) <> "" Then
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
                "=IFS(RC[-2] = """","""",((RC[-1]-RC[-2])*24*60)<0,"""",(RC[-1]-RC[-2])*24*60,(RC[-1]-RC[-2])*24*60)"
        'ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(CR, 3) = _
         ' (ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(CR, 2) - ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(CR, 1)) * 24 * 60
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(TS).Cells(CR + 1, CC - 1).Select


    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Module4

```vb
Sub StartStopButtonClick()
'Macro assigned to the Start/Stop button. Automatically executes the TimeStartStop and checkIdle subs upon being clicked

    Dim lA As Long
    'Last non-blank cell of column A (Start)

    Dim lB As Long
    'Last non-blank cell of column B (Finish)

    Dim lC As Long
    'The next blank cell right below lA


        lA = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        lB = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

        lC = lA + 1

    If lA = 4 Then
    'For a completely blank file
        lA = 6
        lB = 6
        Cells(lA, 1).Select

    ElseIf lA <> lB Then
    'If there's an unfinished cycle, go to the Finish cell
        Cells(lA, 2).Select


    ElseIf lA = lB Then
    'If there are no running cycles, go to the next empty Start cell
        Cells(lC, 1).Select

    Else:
        Debug.Print "Call Tech Support"
    End If

    'Execute the following modules:
    Call Module3.TimeStartStop
    Call Module2.checkIdle
End Sub
```

[This is how the worksheet looks.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L1xsa.png)

The cells in column C (Cycle Time) are supposed to lock once data has been entered into it via the macro (which calculates the cycle time using the start and finish times).

Admittedly, deleting/getting rid of rows is a pain in the butt. I had to make a user manual to serve as a guide for doing so.

**Everything works fine**, it's just that **when I switch to another Excel file (even if it was opened previously), the timer stops**.

**I would like the macro to continue running even if the user switches to another Excel file or opens a new Excel file.**

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: You should try to eliminate every 'ActiveSheet' and 'ActiveCell' from your code. I dont know if that is the only problem, but you will allways encounter problems with code that depends on that.

Comment: @Jochen was about to suggest something similar... `Application.ActiveSheet.Range....` will always be your current active sheet (i.e.: whatever sheet you have on screen or last selected), so if you open a new workbook, your activesheet will be in the new workbook. If you fully qualify the ranges, you shouldn't have problems. You can always use `ThisWorkbook` for that purpose, it returns the workbook the macro is stored in (assuming is the same workbook). And by fully qualify ranges, means pretty much everything that starts with `Range...`, `Cells...`, `ActiveSheet...`, `ActiveCell...` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said, you need to fully qualify some of the ranges... there is plenty room to make the code more neat, but please see below my changes to qualify the ranges at least.

**ThisWorkbook**

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

    Dim lA As Long
    'Last non-blank cell of column A (Start)

    Dim lB As Long
    'Last non-blank cell of column B (Finish)

    Dim myActiveCell As Range

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")  'Assuming sheet 1
        lA = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
        lB = .Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).row
    End With

    If lA <> lB Then
    'If there's an unfinished cycle, execute the following:
        Set myActiveCell = Range_End_Method
        Call TimeStartStop(myActiveCell)
        ThisWorkbook.Save
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    End If

    If lA = lB Then
    'If there's no unfinished cycle, save the sheet and immediately close the sheet
        ThisWorkbook.Save
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    End If

End Sub
```

**Module 1**

```vb
Option Explicit

Function Range_End_Method() As Range
'Finds the last non-blank cell in a single row or column

Dim FirstBlankCell As Range
Set FirstBlankCell = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

Set Range_End_Method = FirstBlankCell 'should never use Activate if you can help it - and in this case, you can

End Function
```

**Module2**

```vb
Public Sub checkIdle()

    Dim lA As Long
    'Last non-blank cell of column A (Start)

    Dim lB As Long
    'Last non-blank cell of column B (Finish)

    Dim myActiveCell As Range

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheets1")
        lA = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
        lB = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).row
    End With

    'If block for if the sheet is blank
    If lA = 4 Then
        lA = 6
    End If
    If lB = 4 Then
        lB = 6
    End If

    DoEvents
    'Number of seconds idle
    Dim idleSecs As Long: idleSecs = GetIdleSecs()

    If lA <> lB Then
    'If there's a running cycle, execute the following
        'For Debugging purposes; this shows up in the immediate Window which you can open by pressing Ctrl + G
        Debug.Print "Idle for"; idleSecs

        'If number of seconds idle is less than 5 minutes, the timer will continue counting and updating every second
        If idleSecs < 300 Then
            Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"), "checkIdle", False
        End If

        'idleSecs is the number of seconds needed before the whole If Block is executed
        '300 seconds because 5 minutes x 60 seconds
        If idleSecs = 300 Then
            Set myActiveCell = Module1.Range_End_Method
            Call Module3.TimeStartStop(myActiveCell)

            'Save the current workbook
            ThisWorkbook.Save

            'Message box: First parameter is the message body, third parameter is the alert title
            MsgBox "TMS has stopped due to 5 minutes of inactivity. Your workbook has automatically been updated and saved.", , "TMS Stopped"

            'Sub is automatically closed once 5 minutes is reached and the timer is stopped
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If

    If lA = lB Then
        'If there's no running cycle, execute the following:
        'For debugging purposes
        'Debug.Print "Doing nothing..."
    End If

End Sub
```

**Module3**

```vb
Sub TimeStartStop(cell As Range)

CR = cell.row

CC = cell.Column

If CC <= 2 And CR >= 6 Then
    TS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Name 'or just "Sheet1".

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(TS).Cells(CR, CC) = Now
    'ThisWorkbook.Sheets(TS).Cells(CR, CC + 1).Select   'Avoid using select!
    If CC = 2 And ThisWorkbook.Sheets(TS).Cells(CR, 1) <> "" Then
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(TS).Cells(CR, CC + 1).FormulaR1C1 = _
                "=IFS(RC[-2] = """","""",((RC[-1]-RC[-2])*24*60)<0,"""",(RC[-1]-RC[-2])*24*60,(RC[-1]-RC[-2])*24*60)"
        'ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(CR, 3) = _
         ' (ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(CR, 2) - ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(CR, 1)) * 24 * 60

        'ThisWorkbook.Sheets(TS).Cells(CR + 1, CC - 1).Select        'Avoid using select!

    End If
End If
End Sub
```

**Module4**

```vb
Sub StartStopButtonClick()
'Macro assigned to the Start/Stop button. Automatically executes the TimeStartStop and checkIdle subs upon being clicked

    Dim lA As Long
    'Last non-blank cell of column A (Start)

    Dim lB As Long
    'Last non-blank cell of column B (Finish)

    Dim lC As Long
    'The next blank cell right below lA

    Dim myActiveCell As Range   'Pass this value through rather than selecting ranges

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") 'Here the activesheet is the one with the button, obviously... but...
        lA = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
        lB = .Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).row

        lC = lA + 1

        If lA = 4 Then
        'For a completely blank file
            lA = 6
            lB = 6
            Set myActiveCell = .Cells(lA, 1) 'Avoid using Select! Fully qualify the range!

        ElseIf lA <> lB Then
        'If there's an unfinished cycle, go to the Finish cell
            Set myActiveCell = .Cells(lA, 2)


        ElseIf lA = lB Then
        'If there are no running cycles, go to the next empty Start cell
            Set myActiveCell = .Cells(lC, 1)

        Else:
            Debug.Print "Call Tech Support"
        End If

    End With

    'Execute the following modules:
    Call Module3.TimeStartStop(myActiveCell)
    Call Module2.checkIdle
End Sub
```

PS: why the different modules?

Comment: Thank you so much @DarXyde! It's working perfectly, I'm just running into one more error... When I work on another Excel file and the timer finishes, I run into a "Run-time error '1004': Method 'Intersect' of object '_Global' failed" and it points me to Sheet1's line of code: 
Set WorkRng = Intersect(Application.ActiveSheet.Range("A:A"), Target)

I'm guessing it's because of ActiveSheet? I tried using ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") but that didn't work...

Re: separate modules, I'm just fixing up the work of someone else (and I'm honestly just a beginner at VBA)

Comment: Hi again @DarXyde! I just figured it out! I used ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Activate to revert back to the timer sheet. I am so thankful for your help! You're the best! Your answer has been marked as the solution.